# Replacement for css expression

Tags: css

So I have the below code in CSS

```
thead th
{
     top: expression(document.getElementById("divContainer").scrollTop);
}
```

I just want to know whether there is any replacement for the above line which has been introduced in CSS3? If yes how it would be?

Comment: This is generally poor practice, and you can accomplish the same thing with restructured CSS.

Comment: Does overflow: scroll; do that? I don't know much about it but this looks like it's a hack to get IE to work how it's meant to for overflow scroll. I've not seen IE have an issue with such rules so perhaps it only relates to versions we don't have to worry about any more? Maybe someone can elaborate.

Comment: @wunth. There was a problem of fixed table header in IE 8 which the above line solved in older project! Now when we have upgraded the normal fixed positions works fine in chrome but not in IE8 as client has asked to target IE 8 specifically!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`expression()` is a non-standard feature. It does not exist in any level of CSS. It's an old IE specific feature that has been removed from newer versions of IE, and is not coming back.

Since `expression()` is nothing more than a bridge between JavaScript and CSS, the simplest solution is to write the equivalent JavaScript. Exactly what the equivalent code looks like will probably depend on your layout.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening on this. I was unaware that `expression()` is a non-standard feature. But yea, till IE 7 it would have worked great!! Ok. I'll write relevant javascript then!! Thanks for your time!! will mark it as answer in few minutes.. :)